# Change width of Nextflow output text

Tags: nextflow

Is there a way to increase the width of the nextflow stdout? I have looked through the documentation, but I can't see anything. I realise this might be a parameter of the bash environment instead, but also couldn't find a way to change this.

In this instance, there is some information missing from `tag{ sampleID+"-"+MapperVal }` in
all the `Mapping` jobs.

```
executor >  local (1), pbspro (9)
[e0/c2b561] process > GFF_Check (1)                  [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[fe/0aa2b0] process > Mapping (Merged_Barcode09-m... [  0%] 0 of 9
[-        ] process > FormatBams                     -
[-        ] process > IsoQuant                       -
[-        ] process > ESPRESSO_S                     -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a modified version of helloWorld as an example, where I have made the tag extremely long:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process sayHelloWithQuiteALongName {
  input:
    val x
  tag "$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x$x"
  output:
    stdout
  script:
    """
    echo '$x world!'
    """
}

workflow {
  Channel.of('Bonjour', 'Ciao', 'Hello', 'Hola') | sayHelloWithQuiteALongName | view
}
```

Regular parameters trims the line when it gets too long:

`nextflow run hw/main.nf`

```
nextflow run hw/main.nf -ansi-log true
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.6
Launching `hw/main.nf` [deadly_pasteur] - revision: af5625b97b
executor >  local (4)
[80/c3d0ae] process > sayHelloWithQuiteALongName (BonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBo... [100%] 4 of 4 ✔
Hola world!

Hello world!

Ciao world!

Bonjour world!
```

Turning off ansi logging:
`nextflow run hw/main.nf -ansi-log false`

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.6
Launching `hw/main.nf` [big_agnesi] - revision: af5625b97b
[e7/acaa39] Submitted process > sayHelloWithQuiteALongName (BonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjourBonjour)
[f7/33263c] Submitted process > sayHelloWithQuiteALongName (CiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiaoCiao)
[c9/4f9251] Submitted process > sayHelloWithQuiteALongName (HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello)
[05/eeff7a] Submitted process > sayHelloWithQuiteALongName (HolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHolaHola)
Bonjour world!

Ciao world!

Hello world!

Hola world!
```

A downside is that you don't have each job concatenated into a single line.

Comment: You can also disable ANSI logging using the environment variable: `export NXF_ANSI_LOG=false`. You could also use a closure to create your 'long' tag, for example, using _String.multiply()_: `tag { x * 100 }`